# Getting javaScript data send with ajax with Playframework2 DynamicForm object. Error: data={data[undefined]=}

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, playframework-2.2, dynamicform

I am sending Javascript array with ajax using post method like this:

```
$.post(assignmentsubmitAddress, submittedUnitsArray,
```

In returning I am getting `status OK`.

But when I wonna retrieve that data on server with PlayFramework2 Dynamic form object like this:

```
DynamicForm requestData = form().bindFromRequest();
System.out.println(requestData.toString());
```

I am getting in console:

```
Form(of=class play.data.DynamicForm$Dynamic, data={data[undefined]=}, value=Some(Form.Dynamic({undefined=})), errors={})
```

Why I'm getting this:

```
data={data[undefined]=}
```

How can I prepare java script data to be readed with play dynamic form?

How to read java script array in playframework?

Answer (score 0):

The java script array list variable `submittedUnitsArray` is correct.

**BUT** It should be passed to ajax posting function this way:

```
$.post(assignmentsubmitAddress, { 'activitiesArray' : submittedUnitsArray },
```

Now it works.